# I Can't send background notification for google firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, service-worker

I am facing problem for set background notification when my firebase-messaging-sw.js is empty, I have no console log error and can see the FCM token. see the screenshot  [image]

but when try this code for set background notification I got error. here my code

**firebase-messaging-sw.js**

```
import {messaging} from '../components/firebaseConfig'
import { onBackgroundMessage } from "firebase/messaging/sw";
 
onBackgroundMessage(messaging, (payload) => {
  console.log('[firebase-messaging-sw.js] Received background message ', payload);
  // Customize notification here
  const notificationTitle = 'Background Message Title';
  const notificationOptions = {
    body: 'Background Message body.',
    icon: '/firebase-logo.png'
  };

  self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle,
    notificationOptions);
});
```

The error I am getting

> Footer.js:95 An error occurred while retrieving token.  FirebaseError: Messaging: We are unable to register the default service worker. Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope ('http://localhost:3000/firebase-cloud-messaging-push-scope') with script ('http://localhost:3000/firebase-messaging-sw.js'): ServiceWorker script evaluation failed (messaging/failed-service-worker-

[image]

I am using nextjs and placed the firebase-messaging-sw.js in my public directory. When I have nothings inside my firebase-messaging-sw.js I can see the token and no console log error but when place the code for background notification I got the above error and also notification popup not showing for asking permission.